# Nginx 504 Time-out with php-fpm

Tags: nginx, debian, php

I got 504 Gateway Time-out for one of my sites. Please, help to find out why?

Here's my nginx configuration:

```
server {

    listen   80;
    server_name domain.com;
    root /home/user/domain.com;

    error_log /home/user/domain.com/error.log;

    location / {
        try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass  unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
}
```

Nginx error log:

```
$ sudo tail -n 1 domain.com/error.log 
2014/08/21 17:09:35 [error] 16790#0: *30 upstream timed out (110: Connection timed out) while reading response header from upstream, client: 5.18.54.52, server: domain.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock", host: "domain.com"
```

And nothing in php-fpm log:

```
sudo tail -n 1 /var/log/php5-fpm.log
[21-Aug-2014 17:08:31] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

And here my www.conf:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/php5/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

pm = dynamic
pm.max_children = 50
pm.start_servers = 5
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 10
```

Please help me to solve this! Thanks!

Comment: Was the socket actually created? If yes, who is the owner and what are the permissions?

Comment: Sorry, but i'm new to linux and do not know how to check this. =(  But my other sites with same configuration working normally.

Comment: `ls -al /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` will tell you if its created and who owns it and what the permissions are. Also which versions of PHP are you currently using?

Comment: Yes, it's created and owned by www-data: `srw-rw---- 1 www-data www-data 0 Aug 21 17:22 /var/run/php5-fpm.sock` 
I'm using PHP 5.5.15-1~dotdeb.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of PHP 5.5.12 FPM Socket permissions were changed to resolve a security related bug, you can read more about that here -> https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=67060

Your `listen.mode = 0660` should now be set to `listen.mode = 0666` inside of your FPM Pool Configuration. Also make certain that your `listen.owner` and `listen.group` is the same user name/group that is running Nginx. Here is what I have in my setup:

```
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0666
```

I am assuming that your Nginx Configuration has `user www-data;` then simply change the `nginx` reference I have above to `www-data` of course.

As for Nginx here is a working example I am currently using:

```
# PHP-FPM Support
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/nginx.sock;
    include fastcgi.conf;
}
```

I think your Nginx Configuration is just fine, but in case you wanted to try something a little different I'm posting my config as a test for you.

Don't forget to restart PHP-FPM after making any configuration changes too.

Give this a try, I'm certain it should resolve your problem.

Comment: I changed `0660` to `0666`, but problem not solved =( My config of www.conf now: 
`
    listen.owner = www-data
    listen.group = www-data
    listen.mode = 0666
`

Comment: Did you make sure to restart FPM and recheck the socket permissions?

Comment: My other sites work just fine with same config. But not this one, i do not know why?¿ =(

Comment: Yes, i restarted FPM, and nginx too.